# Android object movement when click button

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, onclicklistener, chess

i want to create rectangle object and when click button it goes to the layout x and y directions.in simply i want to create some chess Bord and move rectangle when click button.it means chess Bord have 8*8 rows.when i click some button then based on value in button move object.

Thanks
SSV

Comment: Good question. But what have you tried so far?

Comment: I didn't mean this. What I mean is, show us the code what have you tried so that we could all help you getting you in straight path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use animations: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

and you can activate the animation in the OnClickListener.